# How to loop until Process is running, allow to run 60 seconds, kill the process and break the loop?

Tags: powershell, loops, process, kill, terminate

I tried to repurpose another script to loop until the BCR_MODE_SET process is running, allow to run 60 seconds, kill the process and then break the loop.

If the process is already running and I run just the contents of the loop, it kills the process as it should after 60 seconds.  However, if I run the whole script it never kills the process once the process has started running.

```
Start-Process C:\Userdata\Barcode2COM.exe

for ($i=0; $i -le $max_iterations; $i++)

{
    $proc = Get-Process -Name BCR_MODE_SET

    # keep track of timeout event
    $timeouted = $null # reset any previously set timeout

    # wait up to x seconds for normal termination
    $proc | Wait-Process -Timeout 60 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable timeouted

    if ($timeouted)
    {
        # terminate the process
        $proc | kill
    }
    elseif ($proc.ExitCode -ne 0)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: `$max_iterations` doesn't have a value. Is that a copy-paste error?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up simplifying to the following script which accomplishes what I need:

```
Start-Process C:\Userdata\Barcode2COM.exe

DO {$ProcessActive = Get-Process BCR_MODE_SET -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}
While ($ProcessActive -eq $null)

Start-Sleep -Seconds 45

$ProcessActive | kill
```